# How to Maximize SNS throughput?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have an S3 file that contains all the sns endpoints (say 1M devices)

I wanted to push the message out to those 1M device as early as possible once such an S3 file get uploaded (hopefully all get sent to SNS within 1 second)

- Would SNS pose any limit to the throughput per second?
- what would be a best way to make the above happen?